# Big AND and OR symbols (eg, $\bigwedge_{i=1}^9$ and $\bigvee_{j=1}^9$) in discrete math course

Tags: logic, notation, propositional-calculus

I'm taking a Discrete Math course this fall and am very familiar with most of the notation until we got to a certain point in propositions.

At the beginning of some propositions there are big AND or OR symbols, with similar notation to a sum operator.

I tried looking it up, but all my Googles and searches returned nothing.

Like an example in the textbook is the n-queens problem:
$$\bigwedge_{i=1}^9\bigwedge_{n=1}^9\bigvee_{j=1}^9p(i, j, n)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A big $\bigwedge$ (`\bigwedge`) means that instead of summing or multiplying the terms together, you logically AND them, and similarly for a big $\bigvee$ (`\bigvee`) and ORing together.

Comment: Thank you, it is not mentioned once in my textbook for some reason, but it shows up! Very much appreciated.